# DateFormatters with pandas plotting using a DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm struggling to get to grips with date formatting in python pandas plots. I want to be able to trim my dates to just the month on the x-axis.

```
                      Amount (EUR)                                                                                            
Transaction type Cash26 Withdrawal Direct Debit Direct Debit Reversal    Income MasterCard Payment MoneyBeam Outgoing Transfer
Date                                                                                                                          
2020-02-29                  -400.0       -73.86                   NaN  13678.00            -862.01       NaN         -16521.00
2020-03-31                  -450.0      -268.00                  30.0   1431.00            -223.03       NaN          -1889.65
2020-04-30                     NaN          NaN                   NaN  18804.00           -1177.51       NaN         -17889.00
2020-05-31                     NaN          NaN                   NaN   1000.00           -1105.95       NaN               NaN
2020-06-30                  -100.0          NaN                   NaN   5479.01            -955.38       NaN          -4337.00
2020-07-31                     NaN          NaN                   NaN       NaN            -120.84       NaN               NaN
2020-08-31                  -200.0          NaN                   NaN   3300.00            -647.60       NaN           -230.00
2020-09-30                     NaN          NaN                   NaN       NaN           -1454.61       NaN            -50.50
2020-10-31                  -200.0       -25.21                   NaN  12180.00           -1278.63    -100.0          -1917.42
2020-11-30                  -400.0       -18.44                   NaN    590.74           -1509.21       NaN          -2104.62



<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 10 entries, 2020-02-29 to 2020-11-30
Freq: M
Data columns (total 7 columns):
 #   Column                                 Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------                                 --------------  -----  
 0   (Amount (EUR), Cash26 Withdrawal)      6 non-null      float64
 1   (Amount (EUR), Direct Debit)           4 non-null      float64
 2   (Amount (EUR), Direct Debit Reversal)  1 non-null      float64
 3   (Amount (EUR), Income)                 8 non-null      float64
 4   (Amount (EUR), MasterCard Payment)     10 non-null     float64
 5   (Amount (EUR), MoneyBeam)              1 non-null      float64
 6   (Amount (EUR), Outgoing Transfer)      8 non-null      float64
dtypes: float64(7)
```

I am creating my graph using:

```
grouped_dataframe_unstacked = grouped_dataframe.unstack()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 10))
grouped_dataframe_unstacked.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax, stacked=True)
plt.show()
```

I have a feeling that something is broken with these major tick labels but I can't find any guidance online.

```
for i in ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels():
    print(i)

Text(0, 0, '2020-02-29 00:00:00')
Text(0, 0, '2020-03-31 00:00:00')
Text(0, 0, '2020-04-30 00:00:00')
Text(0, 0, '2020-05-31 00:00:00')
Text(0, 0, '2020-06-30 00:00:00')
Text(0, 0, '2020-07-31 00:00:00')
Text(0, 0, '2020-08-31 00:00:00')
Text(0, 0, '2020-09-30 00:00:00')
Text(0, 0, '2020-10-31 00:00:00')
Text(0, 0, '2020-11-30 00:00:00')
```

`rcParams["date.autoformatter.month"] = "%b %Y"` seems to have no effect.

I have tried using various 'set_major_locator' options but it seems to break things.

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b'))
```

I get an error `ValueError: DateFormatter found a value of x=0, which is an illegal date; this usually occurs because you have not informed the axis that it is plotting dates, e.g., with ax.xaxis_date()`.

I have a feeling that my dates are not being passed into the chart properly. Can anyone guide me on how to fix this?

Thanks,

Andrew[image: my graph with broken dates]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there are some collisions between formatters and locators
and the way how the picture is generated when called from a DataFrame.

But you can format dates in an axis you can call e.g. *set_xticklabels*
with properly formatted dates.

I propose also another correction, concerning the title of the legend.
In your picture, *None* at the start is printed because the name of the
top level of the column MultiIndex is just *None*.
To avoid it, you have to drop the top level of the column index.

To generate your plot, use the following code (*df* is your source
DataFrame):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
df.droplevel(level=0, axis=1).plot(kind='bar', ax=ax, stacked=True, width=0.8)
ax.set_xticklabels(df.index.to_series().dt.strftime('%b %Y'), rotation=30)
ax.set_xlabel('Month')
plt.show()
```

Another corrections are:

- I added *width=0.8* because otherwise bars are (in my opinion) too
  narrow,
- I changed the *x* axis title to *Month*, as the original *Date*
  does not reflect used labels,
- I set *x* labels rotation to *30 deg* (in my opinion now they look
  better).

For your data sample I got the following picture:

[image]

It is up to you whether / where to put *Amount (EUR)* (the name of
the top level in the column index). Maybe add it as the title.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reformatting the date column in the original dataframe to only include the month? Assuming the date column is a datetime type, you could do something like:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.month
```

If the Date is a string (not a date), you could do something like

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.month
```

Both of these solutions will convert your Date columns into a month only.